# How to rewrite a chain of else if using when

Tags: kotlin

So I am trying to use when in Kotlin, instead of the chain of else if statements that I have.

```
 companion object {
        private fun min(a: Date?, b: Date?): Date? {
        return if (a == null) b else if (b == null) a else if (a.before(b)) a else b
```

I want my return type to use when and not the else if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```kotlin
fun min(a: Date?, b: Date?): Date? {
    return when {
        a == null -> b
        b == null -> a
        a.before(b) -> a
        else -> b
    }
}
```

You can also shorten this to:

```kotlin
fun min(a: Date?, b: Date?) = when {
    a == null -> b
    b == null -> a
    a.before(b) -> a
    else -> b
}
```

Comment: why you don't do anything is both is null?

Comment: @DanielJacob If both a and b are null, then this function will return null on the first line (a is null, therefore it returns b, which is null).